# Can you restart a death race?

Tags: mad-max

If I make a big mess of things in the middle of the race, and have no chance of winning or beating the time, can I restart the race? Or do I need to wait for the time to run out? I can't seem to find anywhere to restart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get out of the car you will fail the race and have the option to restart.

Comment: This is indeed the answer I was looking for! Just tried it, and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you lose the death run you can restart or quit to stop racing and to start cruising again